# How to call an Apex method (be it in the form of Apex Web service) from a WF Rule

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage

I am looking for a way to invoke an apex method as part of WF Rule fire without calling a web service hosted in some other platforms and which in turn calling back my apex class exposed as a webservice/rest.

Is it possible to just create an Apex Web Service and call that from the WF Rule > Outbound calls to the Apex Web Service?

Comment: Why don't you call an apex method using the process builder instead?

Comment: In fact I need to call the apex code from an Approval Process Final Approval Actions step. I wanted to update the record type which is calculated on the fly. There are alternatives like additional triggers but I think it would have been spot on if I could have just called an apex method.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to call an apex invocable methods through workflows.
you can set a hidden field flag in your final approval steps. Then use process builder to call the apex code.